# AngularJS PHP ng-repeat string in php function

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I have a ng-repeat list with several items, my .json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",  
    "title": "Lab #3",
    "desc": "iOS App Design.",
    "img": "https://lorempixel.com/774/600/sports/",
    "tags": "App | Nav | Design"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Lab #2",
    "desc": "iOS app.",
    "img": "https://lorempixel.com/774/600/abstract/",
    "tags": "App | Design"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Lab #1",
    "desc": "Logo für dprecht",
    "img": "img/lab/labor-1.jpg",
    "tags": "Logo | Rot | Design",
    "href": ""
  }
]
```

and i have this php inside my ng-repeat:

```
 <?php 
                echo "{{::lab.id}}";   // 1, 2, 3
                $itemid_string = "{{::lab.id}}";
                $itemid_int = intval($itemid_string);


                    var_dump($itemid_string);   // string(12) "1"
                    var_dump($itemid_int);     // int(0)


                echo likes($itemid_string);  // or with $itemid_int

                ?>
```

the likes() php function looks like this:

```
function likes($item_id) {
    global $con;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE item_id='$item_id'");
    $likes = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    return $likes;
}
```

my 'likes' table:

```
1   id Primary Key      int(12)
2   item_id             int(12)
```

I always get 0 as the result of likes(). not sure if i need integer or a string. i tried  "id": 1, in the .json too.

i want to display the correct amount of likes for every post.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you mixed PHP with AngularJS! They are completely different environments. Javascript runs in your browser, PHP runs in the server. Output of PHP will be running in your browser. This means first your PHP code runs in the server, and served to the browser. Then javascript starts running.